# Request failed with "429" status code Raulr \ GooglePlayScraper

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting apps details from google play store using raulr/google-play-scraper laravel package.

So i want to get apps list using it

```
$apps = $scraper->getList('topselling_free', 'SOCIAL');
```

But it gives me a error like

> Request failed with "429" status code

Comment: This is an [open issue on their github repo](https://github.com/raulr/google-play-scraper/issues/8).

Comment: Try: `$app = $scraper->getApp('com.mojang.minecraftpe');` I think this will gives you only one or specific app details right? Try this first and then try to get list!

Comment: I know that but i want apps list

    `$apps = $scraper->getListChunk('topselling_free', 'SOCIAL', 0, 80);`

Like this we get  80 apps.

Comment: Is there anything else you need to do in that package after installation? I mean after composer anything add/update with providers array??

Comment: @HirenGohel it's working fine for me but only applist not get

Comment: @Jerodev you are right

Comment: @Jerodev anything you can suggest for this to get app list